# Cassandra CQL 3.2.1 Clear column data

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I need to clear the data from a column in a table using CQL
I've tried the following test on a single node and it works fine.

But is this going to fly on many nodes and different replication factors?

```
DROP KEYSPACE IF EXISTS testColumnDrop;

CREATE KEYSPACE testColumnDrop WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };

USE testColumnDrop;

CREATE TABLE contracts (
  id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
  licenses varchar
);

INSERT INTO contracts(id, licenses) VALUES('one', '{"number":"1.0"}');
INSERT INTO contracts(id, licenses) VALUES('two', '{"number":"2.0"}');
INSERT INTO contracts(id, licenses) VALUES('three', '{"number":"3.0"}');

SELECT * FROM contracts;

ALTER TABLE contracts DROP licenses;

ALTER TABLE contracts ADD licenses varchar;

SELECT * FROM contracts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it using Docker and a cluster of three nodes, worked fine

Answer (score 1):

From DataStax Documentation:

> ALTER DROP removes the column from the table definition, removes data
>   pertaining to that column, and eventually reclaims the space formerly
>   used by the column. The column is unavailable for querying immediately
>   after being dropped. **The actual data removal occurs during compaction**;
>   data is not included in SSTables in the future. To force the removal
>   of dropped columns before compaction occurs, **use the nodetool
>   upgradesstables command followed by an ALTER TABLE statement**, which
>   updates the table metadata to register the drop.
>
> After re-adding a dropped column, a query does not return values
>   written before the column was last dropped. Do not re-add a dropped
>   column to a table using client-supplied timestamps, which is not a
>   Cassandra-generated write time.
>
> You cannot drop columns from tables defined with the COMPACT STORAGE
>   option.

Hope it helps

Comment: yea I read that, not sure its specific enough for the above - I have run the script on a cluster of tree nodes and works fine - but thanks, good to have that here for reference